# Excel Macro Coding Needed - conditional formatting, duplicates, dashboard data

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried to create my own macro by piecing together various examples copied from multiple help sites but haven't had any success in finding a solution to my data issue. I have a somewhat large file that is analyzing structured and unstructured activity for patients out of their rooms. There is a pivot table built in to this analysis to help separate out different tiers of results. If the solution is to undo some of the table setup, that is fine but I am hoping someone out there has a readily available solution for this.
Here is a screenshot of the worksheet in different stages for reference:

#### Data Sheet

[image: Data Sheet]

I need a macro that will copy the values that correlate with the conditionally formatted cells containing numbers and also pull their first and last name from columns a, b, and c, and paste it into e, f, and g. After the data is pasted, it needs to be deleted from columns a, b, and c. I also need it to repeat this process for the data in columns I, J, and K and paste into M, N, and O just as the first operation and with the same criteria. I am trying to use this to verify that all of the patients have been pulled appropriately from the rosters and verifying the amount of time spent in the activities using their # ID. Below, not available on the screenshot, is a verification method to confirm all the numbers line up. I have recorded myself sorting, filtering, copying, pasting, and deleting to create the macro, but the problem I keep running into is that the number of cells conditionally formatted varies from day to day and I haven't found a way to have a dynamic range for a macro to copy, paste, and delete and keep everything intact. I think I've covered everything someone would need to know to help but if not please let me know and I'll clarify. Thanks!!!

I think this is where the problem may lie (in the copy/paste section):

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ActivityList_STR").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3,_ 
    Criteria1:=RGB(255, 199, 206), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor Range
    ("A4:C8").Select Selection.Copy Range("E4").Select 
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
    SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False Range("A4:C8").Select 
    Application.CutCopyMode = False Selection.ClearContents
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, questions should include a specific programming issue where you expected an outcome but got something else, like an error. Could you share your code and try to explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: Sure! I'll paste the code below. The code works but only if it is the same outcome for the data set each time (only if 5 patients are not involved every time) because I couldn't find a way to have it set as a dynamic range rather than a fixed range. I am relatively new to this and I've found answers for other questions on here so I am hoping that someone here has a solution. I just recorded myself making it manually in hopes that I could get a framework to start with.

Comment: Use the [edit] link to include code in your question - don't post code as a comment - it's almost impossible to read like that. Also include any additional information about the problem IN the question, not (only) in a comment.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, bring your CF conditions into a new column, so that you can directly access the resulting TRUE/FALSE results by either Formulas or VBA.

Depending on what version of Excel you have, you have a number of options to accomplish what you're trying to do here, including:

- Pull all the data into VBA using a Variant Array and use Array
  manipulation
- Pull all the data into VBA using a Variant Array and use Scripting
  Dictionaries
- If you've got Excel 2016 or later, use PowerQuery to pull the data
  into Excel, and shape it how you need it right in the PowerQuery
  interface.
- If you've got Excel 2013 or later, import the separate tables into
  the DataModel and join them on the common field, so that you can
  use a PivotTable to do the reporting you describe. (You can do this
  even if you don't have the PowerPivot add-in in the SKU of Excel you 
  have installed)

Note that both PowerQuery and PowerPivot are available as a free addin if you're running a version between 2010 and the dates I mention above.

PowerQuery and PowerPivot are by far the easiest way to tackle your issue if you're new to the above concepts, and there are plenty of resources on the net and videos on YouTube to get you started.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try!

Comment: Cool. Please mark my answer as useful if you found it so.